# Добавить в скрытый input все id child-элементов блока

Tags: javascript, ajax, drag-n-drop

Необходимо при отправке формы добавить в скрытый input все id child-элементов блока

Сам блок с input-ом

```
<div class="summary droppable" style="min-height:100px" id="drophere">

    <label id = "1" class="badge badge-default draggable">Игры</label>
    <label id = "2" class="badge badge-default draggable">Картинки</label>
    <label id = "3" class="badge badge-default draggable">Помощь</label>
    <label id = "4" class="badge badge-default draggable">Новичок</label>
    <label id = "5" class="badge badge-default draggable">Спойлер</label>

</div>

<input name="tags" type="hidden">
```

Отправка данных

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">



        function CreatePost() {

            var msg   = $('#CreatePost').serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'CreatePosthandler',
            data: msg,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Result').html(data);
            },
            error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Tags = document.getElementById("drophere");
            var Input = document.getElementById("tags");

            for (var i = 0; i < Tags.childNodes.length; i++) {
                Input.value += $(Tags.childNodes[i]).attr("id") + " ";
            }
```